# Custom route with parameters

Tags: zend-framework, routes

I want to make customer route for url which have parameters.

```
 <a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick="window.location='<?php echo 
 $this->url(array('module' => 'courses', 'controller' => 'course', 'action' => 'add', 
'std_id' => $entry['std_id']), 'coursesadd', TRUE); ?>'">add course</a>
```

and here what I make routing

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('courses/std_id/:std_id', 

array('module' => 'courses', 'controller' => 'course', 'action' => 'add'));

$routesArray = array('coursesadd' => $route );

$router->addRoutes($routesArray);
```

But It doesn't route correctly!

Comment: what is it doing wrong? When you navigate to `/course/std_id/5` what happens? I will say that when using the `url()` helper you either have the module/controller/action as key pairs or you have a name for the route. so `$this->url(array('std_id' => $entry['std_id']), 'courseadd')` would be more correct.

Comment: This error occur Zend_Controller_Router_Exception: std_id is not specified

Comment: did that error occur using the url helper or by navigating to a url?

Comment: It occurs when I click on an anchor which have URL helper, but I have a navigation menu in my project, may it cause the problem?!

Comment: probably not, I just wanted to know the method of the test. Of course check and make sure `$entry['std_id']` is being set correctly. you may need the `TRUE` switch in the Url helper. [Url Helper](http://blog.ericlamb.net/2010/04/zend-framework-url-view-helper/) may help explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine, except what RockyFord sad - You should only pass these parameters to url() helper which are required by designated route (when 'default' route is used indeed it requires module, controller, action, but Your 'coursesadd' route requires only std_id parameter). Moreover You should improve Your route a little bit to:

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('courses/:std_id', array(
   'module'     => 'main',
   'controller' => 'product',
   'action'     => 'add',
   'std_id'     => null //default value if param is not passed
));
```

The `param_name/:param_value` construction in Your route is redundant because You already named the parameter, so by using above route You'll get `std_id` param in controller using

```
$this->_getParam('std_id')
```

Default value in route definition would save from throwing `Zend_Controller_Router_Exception: std_id is not specified` but it looks like `$entry['std_id']` is not set.